# How can I force HomeKit to send me a SMS/Notification alert (or email) if the basement floods?

Tags: notifications, homekit

I use HomeKit to simplify home management for the elderly.  One of the things I want to address is the failure of a sump-pump, or flooding condition.

Is there a way I can cause a HomeKit sensor to cause this notification?

Comment: What you might want to consider is using a device that supports both HomeKit and some other standard, like IFTTT. IFTTT is great for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the manufacturer of the sensor you're using. If it supports HomeKit notifications, you can set them by pressing on the device's icon in the Home app.

Answer (score -1):

Apple says if you set up HomeKit on an Apple TV or an iPad that always at home, it acts as a intermediate and lets you keep updated from your iPhone even when you are not at home. Notifications include. Theoretically, it also covers flood sensing.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. This explains how to ensure that the notification is received remotely, not that it's sent in the first place.